# Algoritmo em C - Números primos

Tags: c, algoritmo

O programa tem que fazer uma verificação de números primos, aonde o usuário digite um numero e o programa acha o maior numero primo anterior a ele. o problema do meu programa é que ele não verifica até o fim, por exemplo, se eu escrevo 10 deveria achar 7 mas ele acha 5 sempre 5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*.
  .
  .
  7)receber um numero inteiro e falar o maior numero primo que seja o anterior a este*/

int main()
{
    int opc;/*1-switch*/
    int numA=0, numB=0, numC=0, soma, aux=0; /*variaveis para calculos*/
    int i, j;/*contadores*/
    int vet[10];/*vetores inteiros*/
    float media;/*variaveis para calculos*/

    printf("escolha qual exercicio quer executar:\n7)Ex7\n");
    scanf("%i", &opc);

    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");

    switch(opc)
    {
        /*.
          .
          .
          */
    case 7:

        printf("digite um numero:\t");
        scanf("%i", &numA);

        /*inicio da fase de processamento*/

        numB=1; /*para dar inicio ao calculo de achar numero primos por tentativas*/
        numC=0;
        j=0;/*reset do contador*/
        int cont=0, y, aux2=0;

        if(numA==0 || numA==1 || numA==2)
        {
            printf("%i nao tem numero primo, anterior a ele.", numA);
            break;
        }else
        {
            for(i=0; i<numA; i++)
            {
                aux=cont/2;
                for(y=0; y<aux; y++)
                {
                    numC=cont%numB;/*faz divisao modular da variavel de entrada com     numB=1*/

                    fflush(stdin);

                    if(numC==0)/*verifica se resultado deu 0*/
                        j=j+1;/*se sim armazena em j um marcador +1/+1*/

                    numB=numB+1;/*e soma 1 ao numB para acompanhar o valor de aux*/
                }

                fflush(stdin);

                if(j==1)
                {
                    aux2=cont;
                }

                cont=cont+1;
                j=0;/*reset do contador*/

                printf("\n\n\n[%d]\n\n\n", aux2);/*verificação de variavel*/                
                printf("\n\n\n%d\n\n\n", cont);
            }

            printf("%d eh o maior numero primo antes de %i", aux2, numA);
        }

        /*fim da fase de processamento*/

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> SOLUÇÃO ENCONTRADA

```
/*inicio da fase de processamento*/

    for(i=0; i<numA; i++)
    {
        aux=numA-1;/*subtraio 1 ao numero original*/

        if(comPrimos(aux)==true)/*mando para uma função o valor armazenado na aux para verificar se é primo*/
        {/*se for verdadeiro faça*/
            printf("%d eh o maior numero primo antes de %i", aux, aux2);
            break;/*quebrar para sair do for*/
        }

        numA=aux;
    }

    /*fim da fase de processamento*/
```

> FUNÇÃO

```
int comPrimos(int prim)
{
    int i, aux, B, j=0;

    aux=prim/2;

    int A=1;

    for(i=0; i<aux; i++)
    {/*verificação por tentativas de divisão modular*/
        B=prim%A;

        if(B==0)
            j=j+1;

        A=A+1;
    }

    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");

    if(j==1)
        return true;

    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: Permita-me uma sugestão: comece por escrever uma função que verifique se um número é primo. Depois chame essa função com o valor digitado menos um. Se a função retornar `true` foi encontrado o resultado se não subtraia 1 e volta a chamar a função. Faça isto é até que a função retorne `true`

Comment: obrigado viu @ramaral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como parece ser um problema didático vou apenas deixar uma sugestão, não sei se pode ser válido aqui no `Stak`. Se não for posto o código depois.

Eu começaria a pensar de uma forma diferente, imagina que o usuario entra com um nmr muito alto,o sistema vai de 0 até chegar perto desse numero, por que em vez de começar de 0 o loop vc nao começa do numero que o usuario entrou, ai vc decrementa i a cada interação, e assim que achar o primeiro numero primo vc sai do laço, economizando processamento e dispensando variaveis temporarias, a função for seria mais o menos assim

```
    for(i=numA-1; i>0; --i)
          if(isPrimo(i)){
                printf(" primo anterior %d", i);
                break;
          }
```

Comment: ainda nao testei estou em aula

Comment: verdade, é mais facil pegar logo o primeiro numero de traz pra frente que seja primo

Comment: então eu fiz aqui parecido com o seu vou postar embaixo do cogido que postei vai estar escrito solução para dividir @Abraão

Answer (score 1):

Bom ai vai um exemplo de solução para o seu problema. Ela é baseada em gerar um vetor contendo 1 para os números que são primos e 0 para os números que não são, é o famoso crivo de Eratóstenes. Ou seja crivo[19] vai retornar 1, pois 19 é primo e crivo[25] vai retornar zero, pois 25 não é primo.

O crivo é feito iniciando como se todos os números fossem primos, dai se tira todos os múltiplos de 2, depois todos os múltiplos de 3, depois de 5 e assim em diante até que só sobram os números primos.
Depois de montar o crivo o resto do programa fica bem fácil de fazer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define tamanho_crivo 10000

int main()
{
    int num, i, j, resp=0;

    // Monta o vetor para determinar se um número é primo ou não
    char crivo[tamanho_crivo];
    memset(crivo, 1, tamanho_crivo);
    crivo[0] = 0;
    crivo[1] = 0;
    for(i=2; i < tamanho_crivo; i++){
        if(crivo[i] == 1)
            for(j=2*i; j < tamanho_crivo; j = j+i)
                crivo[j] = 0;  // Números que não são primos, pois são divisíveis por i 
    }

    printf("Digite um numero inteiro positivo:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    for(i=num; i > 1; i--)
        if(crivo[i]){
            resp = i;
            break;
        }

    // Imprime os resultados
    if(resp==0)
        printf("Nao tem numero primo anterior\n");
    else
        printf("%d e o maior numero primo antes de %d\n", resp, num);

    return 0;
}
```